# How can I symlink /data mount point to preseve it on reboot?

Tags: partitions

There is a link under `/emmc@usrdata` which points to the emmc data partition which is `/dev/block/mmcblk0p7` (which is small).

I have created a 4GB EXT4 formatted second partition on  SD card, which is `/dev/block/mmcblk1p2`

In `fstab` the device name used for the `/data` mount is the link `/emmc@usrdata`. I have tried removing this link and creating a new one pointing to the new partition, but on reboot the symlink points to the original one again.

How can I make this symlink stick?

I haven't been able to find a script that writes the symlinks to root on startup, but there must be one there somewhere. The device is an MTK based phablet. ( Aries_7O ). Any clues would be appreciated.